# Get unformatted Alexa value from built-in AMAZON.DURATION slot type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I'm using the `AMAZON.DURATION` built-int [slot type](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#duration) to get data from my custom Alexa skill. This works perfectly and converts the given duration to an ISO-8601 duration format.

For example, the slot type successfully converts "ten minutes" to `PT10M` and I can get this data from the request object passed to my Lambda function.

However, I would also like to pass the unformatted "ten minutes" to my Lambda function, too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I asked this same [question](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/56472/get-unformatted-value-from-built-in-amazonduration.html) in the Amazon Developer forums and the official response from Amazon is:

> Hi, this isn't possible although it is an interesting request!

I ended up writing a manual conversion function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Should manually convert it. Below is the code snippet for nodejs to convert to minutes. Lets assume Alexa sends PT5M to Lambda

```
var time = "PT5M";
var res = time.substring(2, (time.length));
var mins;
var timelist = res.split("H");
if(timelist.length > 1){
    mins = +parseInt((timelist[0]*60),10)+parseInt((timelist[1].substring(0,(timelist[1].length-1))),10);
}else{
    mins = res.substring(0, (res.length-1));
}
console.log(mins);
```